# Cannot access values in $state?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

In a AngularJS service I use $log to look at my url parameter values so if I

```
$log.debug('$state', $state);
```

I can read $state.params.db 's value on the firefox console but if I

```
$log.debug('$state.params.db', $state.params.db);
```

I get undefined
Same behaviour with $stateParams.

Comment: When are you running the `$log` function? It could be that `params` isn't populated when you run the call, but is populated by the time you expand `$state` in the console.

Comment: can you post your controller code or create a plunker for the same

Comment: Matt Way was right. I got a "resolve" on state that uses a service that has a dependency on $state so... sorry for bad question